# Windows 10 Update Assistant UI disappeared

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am updating to Windows 10 version 16299, from version 15063 (as we speak).  At first, the Update Assistant showed me a UI that had a running percentage on the top left corner.  However, I did a "clear desktop" (Windows key D), and the UI for the Update Assistant disappeared.  I know it is downloading in the background, because I see it running in the Windows Task Manager, and there is sustained and stable network download traffic.

Is there any way to bring back the UI of a Windows app that is running but has disappeared?  (Note: Re-issuing another "Windows D" command did not help.)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to Show Hidden Icons on the right side of the taskbar, click the up arrow and you’ll see the Windows Update Assistant icon there. Click on it and the Getting your update ready screen will re-appear.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **shortcut** on the desktop that when clicked will pop up the UI on the screen.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In task manager, can you expand the process under Apps and then right click on the child item and select "switch to" on the child task (Or maximize/bring to front for that matter)?  That should bring it back into view.

Editing to add in what was in a comment:  If the screen disappears, then just wait- once it is finished downloading, Windows will prompt for the installation of the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, a "switch to" or similar option does not exist in the Task Manager for the item.  Incidentally, the application is listed under Background tasks, not Apps.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that'll do it.  Is it not showing up in the system tray area, either?  I thought it normally did.

Comment: No, it's not, it has disappeared but is in the Task Manager's list of running processes only.

Comment: I would say just wait it out-- once it is done downloading, it should pop up and ask you to install it.

Comment: Yes, that's what happened finally.  But the overall update failed with a strange error.  :)

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

1. open task manager
2. locate windows 10 update assistant in background processes
3. right click on it
4. click open file location
5. wait for the folder to open
6. reopen windows 10 update assistant from there it'll restore the icon but won't restart it